# Remotely access local services through wireguard tunnel from mobile

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

**Use-case:** I want to reach services hosted at home through vpn on-the-go from mobile (and I don't want to tunnel them 1-by-1).

I have the below topology:
[image: My network topology]

I have setup wireguard based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/insdavm/b1034635ab23b8839bf957aa406b5e39
Except I want split-tunnel on my "fixed client" (Host A in gist). VPS is on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and "fixed client" on 18.04 LTS, both using iptables.

The hosts with-in wg tunnel can ping each-other through the tunnel. However, I cannot ping any host in the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet from the "mobile client".
Ping does reach the destination host, which answers too, but the "fixed client" doesn't send back the response through the wg tunnel:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i wg0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
22:25:50.229878 IP 10.66.76.2 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4271, seq 1, length 64
22:25:54.276140 IP 10.66.76.2 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4272, seq 1, length 64
22:25:58.402260 IP 10.66.76.2 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4273, seq 1, length 64

$ sudo tcpdump -i enp2s0 -n host 192.168.0.67
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:25:26.677816 IP 192.168.0.15 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4268, seq 1, length 64
22:25:26.678704 IP 192.168.0.67 > 192.168.0.15: ICMP echo reply, id 4268, seq 1, length 64
22:25:30.721416 IP 192.168.0.15 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4269, seq 1, length 64
22:25:30.722195 IP 192.168.0.67 > 192.168.0.15: ICMP echo reply, id 4269, seq 1, length 64
22:25:34.742213 IP 192.168.0.15 > 192.168.0.67: ICMP echo request, id 4270, seq 1, length 64
22:25:34.742946 IP 192.168.0.67 > 192.168.0.15: ICMP echo reply, id 4270, seq 1, length 64
```

Why the replies are not sent back through the tunnel when they should be NAT-ed?
Seems the fixed client only use NAT one way, but not in reverse?!

I would expect the ping replies from `192.168.0.67` to be forwarded to `10.66.76.2` as that was the original source before applying NAT.
The same PostUp iptables rule works fine at the VPS: clients tunneling all traffic through the VPS's public IP can access the internet. So I don't understand why my "fixed client" cannot NAT traffic to the local network.

**My wg confs are as below:**
VPS server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.66.76.1/24,fd42:42:52::1/64
ListenPort = 12345
PrivateKey = ...
# Not needed for this scenario, but some clients tunnel all traffic
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens6 -j MASQUERADE

# Mobile client
[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.66.76.2/32, fd42:42:52::2/128

# Fixed client in home network
[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.66.76.4/32, fd42:42:52::4/128, 192.168.0.0/24
```

Mobile client:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.66.76.2/24, fd42:42:52::2/64
MTU = 1420

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = my-vps.net:12345
AllowedIPs = 10.66.76.0/24, fd42:42:52::1/128, 192.168.0.0/24
```

Fixed client:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.66.76.4/24, fd42:42:52::4/64
MTU = 1420
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = my-vps.net:12345
AllowedIPs = 10.66.76.0/24, fd42:42:52::0/64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this finally.
It turned out that I was missing the reverse iptables rule for forwarding into the tunnel:
`iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT`.

So the correct config for the "fixed client" is below:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.66.76.4/24, fd42:42:52::4/64
MTU = 1420
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
Endpoint = my-vps.net:12345
AllowedIPs = 10.66.76.0/24, fd42:42:52::0/64, 172.20.0.0/24
```